# JOOQ concatenation

Tags: java, concatenation, multiple-columns, jooq

I have a query like this:

```
Result<?> result = create.select(CONSUMER.CONS_ID_NO,
                                             CONSUMER.CONS_NAME,
                                             concat(CONSUMER.AREA_CODE, "/", CONSUMER.CONS_NO, "/", CONSUMER.CAT_CODE).as("ConsNo"),
                                             CONSUMER.ARREARS)
                                            .from(CONSUMER)
                                            .fetch();
```

I wrote this according to the [JOOQ Manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual-single-page/#aliased-columns), but I am getting an error that says:

> The method concat(String...) in the type Factory is not applicable for
>   the arguments (TableField, String,
>   TableField, String,
>   TableField)

I am using **JOOQ-3.**

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with JOOQ to put this out as an answer, but wonder if you want to use TableField's .getName() method, to get a string instead of a TableField for CONSUMER.AREA_CODE etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that the sample in the manual doesn't work. However, you can convert a string to Filed via `org.jooq.impl.Factory.val`.

```
    Record result = create.select(
            concat(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, val(" "), AUTHOR.LAST_NAME).as("Full Name")
    ).from(AUTHOR).fetchAny();
```

Please refer to [this email from Lukas Eder](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/qIJlk4JPZCc/7P02gapjLTQJ) for details